# Textfield event is never called in delegate

Tags: iphone, xcode

In my interface I have:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *Stock;
    // ....
}
```

This is the implementation I have:

```
- (BOOL)Stock:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([[textField text] isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }    
    return YES;
}
```

In the `viewDidLoad` I have `Stock.delegate = self`;

I am expecting this method is called after any character is typed in the text field.  But this routine is never called.   What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I had the delegate in place but for some reason this site truncated my message.  Also I added Stock.delegate = self;  Still this does not work.  Please note this is a textfield and not textview.  Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a UITextField, you've just implemented a random method. The actual delegate method is

-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Try providing that one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wire the TextField (Stock in your case) Delegate to FileOwner ?

If not then try this in viewDidLoad method of the Controller

```
Stock.delegate = self;
```

Or you can just wire it in IB.

Comment: Thanks added it as you suggested.  Still not working.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare `MainViewController` conforming `UITextFieldDelegate`:

   `@interface MainViewController : UIViewController < UITextFieldDelegate >`
2. To be called this method of UITextFieldDelegate should be declared as:

   `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`
3. In code or in `IB` `MainViewController` should be set to be `delegate`.

Correct and it will be fired as supposed.

Comment: I had the delegate in place but for some reason this site truncated my message. Also I added Stock.delegate = self; Still this does not work. Please note this is a textfield and not textview. Appreciate any help.

Comment: @saman01, UITextFieldDelegate protocol has absolutely the same method (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string. And if you has declared UIViewController conforming to UITextViewDelegate protocol and set delegate property, the only problem - your declaration of shouldChangeCharactersInRange differs from such in UITextViewDelegate protocol. So it's another method. That's why it is never fired. Pay attention on "Stock:" at the beginning.